# Designing Leaderboard Scores in DDD

Tags: microservices, domain-driven-design, ddd-service, dddd, domain-data-modelling

There are two entities around this problem, mainly

1. Leaderboard - Which holds the info about type(lowest first/highest first), description, name etc.
2. Score - The score value submitted by the player which holds player details along with score value

Usecases:

1. We need to fetch scored who are top 10
2. For a monthly leaderboard, we need to find top 3

Domain Rules:

1. A player can submit any number of scores
2. The leaderboard ranking needs to be based on the type defined in leaderboard (lowest/highest)

For such a system where

1. Leaderboard and scores has 1 to many relationship
2. Score needs to have info about the player information(which is a separate aggregate root and in different Bounding Context)

**How to design it in DDD?**

**Scenario 1:**
Does Leaderboard will be aggregate root and Scores will be added through Leaderboard aggregate root (for every score)?

Queries:

1. Here, scores doesn't have a meaning without Leaderboard, and also no domain rules insist to add a score via Leaderboard aggregate root. This is in-fact a dilemma and how to handle this?
2. How to get the Player details to feed in score? Do I need to fetch the player details in a domain service and feed the Leaderboard Aggregate root while adding the score?

**Scenario 2**:
Leaderboard and LeaderboardScore are **two different** Aggregate roots.

Queries:

1. While calculating ranks, we need to fetch scores from score aggregate root and type info from leaderboard and fulfil the use-case?
2. Here most of the use-case serving code  needs to be in Domain Service or Application Service?

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it with score and leaderboard being their own aggregates.  Score changes publish domain events which get fed (asynchronously, since eventual consistency is probably OK) to update the leaderboard.

Comment: When and where to calculate the ranking?

Comment: The leaderboard maintains its own view (eventually consistent) of what the scores are.

Comment: The leaderboard keeps a list of the top 10 scores. When a new score event is received, the leaderboard checks if it's higher (or lower) than any of the top 9 scores. If it is, it pushes the other scores down and discards the 11th, if not, it ignores it.